# Oracle db: How to update with the results of a function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this one:

```
id1 | id2 | start_date | end_data
```

where id1, id2 and start_data shape the primary key.
Bellow you can see an example:

```
- 5624 |    JK  |   16/06/2017  |   20/06/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   20/06/2017  |   22/06/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   27/09/2017  |   01/10/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   09/10/2017  |   (null)
- . . .
```

So I want to update the start_date with the value of end_data of the previous column.

```
- 5624 |    JK  |   16/06/2017  |   20/06/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   20/06/2017  |   22/06/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   22/06/2017  |   01/10/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   01/10/2017  |   (null)
- . . .
```

I will delete the primary key temporarily.

I try to use the LAG function and I get:

```
- id1 | id2 | start_date | end_data | LAG
__________________________________________
- 5624 |    JK  |   16/06/2017  |   20/06/2017 | (null)
- 5624 |    JK  |   20/06/2017  |   22/06/2017 | 20/06/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   27/09/2017  |   01/10/2017 | 22/06/2017
- 5624 |    JK  |   02/10/2017  |   (null)     | 01/10/2017 
- . . .
```

How can I use the result of LAG function to update every row with his value in start_date column? Do you guys think that I can use a different approach to reach my target?

Comment: One way you can do is write a procedure which will open cursor with LAG function and use the cursor values to update respective column.

Comment: I've already done that with a procedure and it works. But I wanted to know if it was possible to make with a query

Comment: One way is to use [ROWID pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) as a "temporary replacement" of the primary key value in a subquery, then [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) a result of the subquery into the table. This can be done only on the assumption that the other processes do not modify this table at the same time (esspecially don't delete and insert new rows), because in such a case a rowid of deleted row can be reassigened to a newly inserted row.

Comment: Are the start/end dates considered separately for each "grouping" by `id1` and `id2`? Or only by one of the id's? Or by none? Then: When you use analytic functions (like you are) for an update, it is often easier with the `merge` statement - are you familiar with it, and did you consider it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LAG` with `UPDATE` directly:

```
UPDATE t
SET START_DATE = 
   (SELECT nws
    FROM (SELECT rowid, COALESCE(LAG(END_DATA)
          OVER(PARTITION BY ID1, ID2 ORDER BY END_DATA ASC), START_DATE) AS nws
          FROM t) s 
    WHERE s.rowid = t.rowid);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=90c6a2a1cf433fc333f31f6010c93d3c)**

Comment: Each update statement creates an **implicit** cursor - however, I assume we all know what you mean: *You don't need **explicit**  CURSOR*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I take a different view of this issue. "Cursor" is an implementation concept; ideally, as a developer I shoun't have to have ever even heard of "cursors". Just with standard SQL knowledge, I should be able to write an UPDATE statement, like lad2025 demonstrated.

Comment: You shouldn't need `COALESCE`; rather, add the condition `nws is not null` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes you are right, it was mental shortcut.